# How can I manage Microsoft Windows user accounts from Linux?

Tags: windows, users

Is there any way to **manage the user accounts** for any **Windows** operating system installed on my hard disk **from Linux**?
I.e: by booting some live distro and making all desired changes.

The **more useful** changes I can think of are:

- **Adding** privileged (admin) user accounts.
- **Changing** passwords.

Some more capabilities (like user deletion, privileges modification or groups management) are, also, welcome.

Answers desired for every Windows version.
If specific, modern versions (Windows 10, as for today, Aug 2018) preferred.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about performing admin tasks on a Windows system (albeit from Linux).

Comment: Make Windows use an LDAP server, manage LDAP from Linux? Of course you won't be able to manage local Windows accounts. And setting up the LDAP server may prove ... interesting.

Comment: There is a linux based environment on the hirens boot cd that is able to reset windows passwords.

Comment: @Kusalananda Maybe you could interpret the question as a way to improve the cooperation of Unix with the external world. Also I dislike windows, but the capability of the unix to interact with it, helps the open world and doesn't harm it.

Comment: The tool what you are looking for is [chntpw](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/chntpw/chntpw.8.en.html), available in all mainstream distros.

Comment: @dirkt Yes, also samba tools have a limited capability to administer a windows domain (I never did it, only in the other direction), but the OP doesn't wants this. The OP wants to manage windows users on his windows partition.

Comment: @Jesse_b [chntpw](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/chntpw/chntpw.8.en.html), with a minimal wizardry can be even used from ubuntu live cd-s.

Comment: @peterh I'm more than happy for the question to be reopened, no worries. Especially if it's been closed erroneously.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there are any tools to manage local Windows user accounts in a Windows disk image, other than the one that resets the local administrator account. (I'm being vague there because I can't remember its name.)

If you have a running Windows image and if domain joined then I understand that SAMBA provides tools for domain user management. (I haven't used them, though, as it's easier in a mixed environment to use the native Windows tools.)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a dual-boot setup on your computer, your best bet might be using ntpasswd (http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).

If you mean to manage your active directory environment from your linux system, you can try adtool (https://gp2x.org/adtool/), or see if powershell would help you here (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6)